# How to Set DateTimeFields in Django Models to None Value (If current time is greater than this fields with auto detect)

Tags: django, django-models, time, automation

Below is my codes

```
class Job(models.Model):
      pin_till = models.DateTimeField("Pin Job Post", null=True,blank=True)
```

Here i wanna auto setup pin_till_date field to None if date is not None and than pin_till_date < now().  Depend on current time and auto check this field to None.
How to archives this method ah? with @property function, signals or just define in save function?

Answer (score 1):

You can *Override Save()*

```
class Job(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pin_till < now(): # Or what ever be the condition
        # Use your conditon and update 
           self.pin_till = None 
    super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #Save the modified value
```

Comment: This will auto check current time and change fields to None? i did write like this but concern this will not auto detect with current time

Comment: Yes, Each time the model is loaded, this code will execute. So if you use something like datetime.now() inside code it will return the current time.

Comment: hi sir, not work ah. Even pin_till < now(), value still exist. need to call save to make this empty ah.

Comment: @SunGoKu updated the code like your condition. I think this will normally work Or I dn't get your correctly.